# How to login using openid in VSCode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, authorization, openid, vscode-extensions

I need some inputs/suggestions on how to login into VSC extension. I have already done similar stuff for web application in angular using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client library.

I am developing VSC extension(typescript language) in which I have to authenticate users before they use it. For that, I have cloudIDP auth URL to which I have to forward the request for users to get logged in first. Once user is logged in, Users should come back to VSC extension and then start using in-built extension commands.

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client library with code flow. I am able to open login url, getting users loggedin, coming back to vscode extension but without token.

```
let req = Client.authorizationUrl({
    client_id: 'CLIENT:ID',
    client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
    redirect_uri: 'vscode://EXTENSION_NAME/auth',
    scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
    response_type: ['code'],
    code_challenge,
    code_challenge_method: 'S256',
});

//This opens browser window from vscode and user gets logged in and comes back to extension
vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.parse(req)).then((response) => {
    console.log('Signin response: ', response); // returns true
    // not sure how to proceed here
});
```

Is my approach right or do I need to do anything else here ?

Please guide me, Thanks in advance.

Alpesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

After redirection, I have to handle logic in UriHandler class and then hitting the api for getting token there with the code params as received in after redirection.

Let me know if you want to understand (or in future), I would love to guide there.

Regards,
Alpesh

Comment: Hey Alpesh I'm currently working in a similar task and hitting the same issue. How did you set up the client in your openId serve

Comment: Hello @PereFernandez, one of my teammates setup the client there and just shared client information

Comment: Hi Alpesh! Could you please share some code or create a sandbox if possible on the uri handler part? I'm developing an extension too and stuck at the same problem currently with uri handler

Comment: @MiliDubey https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#UriHandler
when user is logged in to the browser window opened from vscode, it will receive all the information in this function - vscode.UriHandler